# 400 Error When Sending JSON to Controller

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I try to send a JSON object from JavaScript to Controller. I get 400 status code when sending the object. I tried many methods, but my last approach is below. Do I miss something? Why do I keep getting 400?

ajax post call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/services/saveReservation",
  cache: false,
  data: saveReservation,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(data) {
    console.debug("After success");
  }
});
```

my object looks like this:

```
{  
   "accommodaion":"a0d8185c-a238-5qe7-aa48-5c196b108aba",
   "totalOutputPrice":90,
   "bookerInfo":{  
      "country":"xa",
      "homeAddress":"",
      "phoneNumber":"0019382663773",
      "contactChoice":"phone",
      "name":"test name",
      "id":"87"
   },
   "creditCard":{  
      "holderName":"holder test",
      "cardType":"discover",
      "cardNumber":"6011303031648258",
      "expMonth":"01",
      "expYear":"2017",
      "cvc":"123"
   },
   "checkIn":"2016-11-16 06:43:19.77",
   "checkOut":"2017-03-16 06:43:19.77",
   "totalTax":4,
   "totalVat":13,
   "roomOutputPrice":"77"
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveReservation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public test saveReservation(
  @RequestBody test saveReservation) {
  System.out.println(saveReservation.getAccommodaion());
  System.out.println(saveReservation.getBookerInfo().getName());
  System.out.println(saveReservation);
  return saveReservation;
}
```

Classes:

```
private class bookerInfo {
    private String country;
    private String homeAddress;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String contactChoice;
    private String name;
    private String id;
    //getters setters
}
private class creditCard {
    private String holderName;
    private String cardType;
    private String expMonth;
    private String expYear;
    private String cvc;
    //getters setters
}
private class test {
    private String accommodaion;
    private Float totalOutputPrice;
    private bookerInfo bookerInfo;
    private creditCard creditCard;
    private String checkIn;
    private String checkOut;
    private Float totalTax;
    private Float totalVat;
    private Float roomOutputPrice;
    //getters setters
}
```

Error in framework:

```
16:12:14,096 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler [public ba.projectService.controller.test ba.projectService.controller.G2BController.saveReservation(ba.projectService.controller.test)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "cardNumber" (class ba.projectService.controller.creditCard), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "cvc", "expMonth", "holderName", "cardType", "expYear"])
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@793ea01d; line: 1, column: 287] (through reference chain: ba.projectService.controller.test["creditCard"]->ba.projectService.controller.creditCard["cardNumber"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cardNumber" (class ba.projectService.controller.creditCard), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "cvc", "expMonth", "holderName", "cardType", "expYear"])
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@793ea01d; line: 1, column: 287] (through reference chain: ba.projectService.controller.test["creditCard"]->ba.projectService.controller.creditCard["cardNumber"])
16:12:14,099 DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler [public ba.projectService.controller.test ba.projectService.controller.G2BController.saveReservation(ba.projectService.controller.test)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "cardNumber" (class ba.projectService.controller.creditCard), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "cvc", "expMonth", "holderName", "cardType", "expYear"])
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@793ea01d; line: 1, column: 287] (through reference chain: ba.projectService.controller.test["creditCard"]->ba.projectService.controller.creditCard["cardNumber"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cardNumber" (class ba.projectService.controller.creditCard), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "cvc", "expMonth", "holderName", "cardType", "expYear"])
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@793ea01d; line: 1, column: 287] (through reference chain: ba.projectService.controller.test["creditCard"]->ba.projectService.controller.creditCard["cardNumber"])
16:12:14,099 DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:134 - Resolving exception from handler [public ba.projectService.controller.test ba.projectService.controller.G2BController.saveReservation(ba.projectService.controller.test)]: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "cardNumber" (class ba.projectService.controller.creditCard), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "cvc", "expMonth", "holderName", "cardType", "expYear"])
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@793ea01d; line: 1, column: 287] (through reference chain: ba.projectService.controller.test["creditCard"]->ba.projectService.controller.creditCard["cardNumber"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "cardNumber" (class ba.projectService.controller.creditCard), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "cvc", "expMonth", "holderName", "cardType", "expYear"])
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@793ea01d; line: 1, column: 287] (through reference chain: ba.projectService.controller.test["creditCard"]->ba.projectService.controller.creditCard["cardNumber"])
```

Comment: can you post a log of the error?

Comment: Expliciting the media type, maybe... @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})

Comment: I posted the error. @SannonAragão I added consumes section, but I still get 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to serialize your javascript object with JSON.stringify.

Try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/services/saveReservation",
  cache: false,
  data: JSON.stringify(saveReservation),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false,

  success: function(data) {
    console.debug("After success");
  }
});
```

And add the content type to the request mappging:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveReservation", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Make sure you have defined the json message converters. If you have Jackson as dependecy Spring do it for you.

---

Your new message is clear. You are sending a property from javascript that does not exist in your class. I am not sure whether you made a mistake or it is what you want. The property "cardNumber" does not exist at your CreditCard bean.

You can configure Jackson to ignore the unknown properties without throwing an exception using the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at the top of your class.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
private class creditCard {
    private String holderName;
    private String cardType;
    private String expMonth;
    private String expYear;
    private String cvc;
    //getters setters
}
```

---

If you want to send more than one credit card you could use a list. So, just changing your test bean to be able to work with a list of cards

```
private class test {
    ...
    private List<creditCard> creditCards;
    ...
    //getters setters
}
```

and at your javascript object, it should be now an array

```
{  
   ... here all your properties

   "creditCards":[{  
      "holderName":"card 1",
      "cardType":"discover",
      "cardNumber":"6011303031648258",
      "expMonth":"01",
      "expYear":"2017",
      "cvc":"123"
   },{  
      "holderName":"card 2",
      "cardType":"discover",
      "cardNumber":"6011303031648258",
      "expMonth":"01",
      "expYear":"2017",
      "cvc":"123"
   },{  
      "holderName":"card 3",
      "cardType":"discover",
      "cardNumber":"6011303031648258",
      "expMonth":"01",
      "expYear":"2017",
      "cvc":"123"
   }],

   ... more properties
}
```

should be enough. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I follow your answer, but still get 400. 
I have jackson bean in my xml.

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
 </bean>.

Also, I added new error which is shown in framework

Comment: I must have missed it... Now I can get values. Thank you so much. 
Also Lets say I have 2 creditCard objects in json. Should I create a for loop, or how can I get those two creditCard information?

Comment: @MalenaT I have updated my answer to let you know how to deal with more than one credit card.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience!